# Tailwind images going are not contained in containers

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am struggling to make my images fill or fit their containers. I want them to take all available of the view and not beyond the view.

```
<div class="flex h-screen max-h-screen border-2">
  <div class="w-1/2">
    <div class="h-12 bg-red-100">here</div>
    <div class="flex-1 border-2 border-red-200">
      <img class="h-full object-contain" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/4000" alt="first image" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-1/2">
    <div class="h-12 bg-red-100">here</div>
    <div class="flex-1 h-full border-2 border-red-200">
      <img class="object-fill" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="test" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/6GMm4k4vxU

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the images' containers and apply `w-full` and `h-full` to both. Then, apply `overflow-hidden` to hide the images' overflowing parts.

Of course, the second image (https://picsum.photos/200/300) will always be blurry because we're scaling it up quite a bit.

You can also remove the `max-h-screen` because we already set a constant height to the screen, which is `100vh` (`h-screen`).

```
<div class="flex h-screen border-2 border-red-600">
  <div class="flex w-1/2 flex-col">
    <div class="min-h-12 bg-red-100">here</div>
    <img class="h-full w-full overflow-hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/4000" alt="test" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-1/2 flex-col">
    <div class="min-h-12 bg-red-100">here</div>
    <img class="h-full w-full overflow-hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="test" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Xsh4sSDs1L)

---

The above method might stretch your images. Here's another solution that should take care of it:

Remove the images thoroughly. We're going to show them as a background image.
We'll start by adding the background's images to `tailwind.config`:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        '1000': "url('https://picsum.photos/1000/1000')",
        '1200': "url('https://picsum.photos/1200/1200')",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can read about this method [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme). You can also read about configuring the default theme [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#customizing-the-default-theme).

We'll then change the structure of the images by splitting our view into two containers (`w-1/2` each). Each container will have an image as a background applied using the custom background we created (`bg-1000` and `bg-1200`).
Each container also has a `div` inside it. This `div` is entirely optional.

```
<div class="flex h-screen border-2 border-red-600">
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-1200">
    <div class="h-12 bg-red-100">here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-1000">
    <div class="h-12 bg-red-100">here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VKl6HuDJta)

Comment: the problem I have with that is that the images gets cut and the some of the image is gone. somehow i am running into kind of the same problem with my overflow on my tables https://play.tailwindcss.com/bWdrHkmC5p i only want to scroll the content not what is below and above.

Comment: @user2915010, You need to set `overflow-auto` and `height` to the `div` containing the table. For example: `overflow-auto h-[50rem]` https://play.tailwindcss.com/XoixpuOcZ3
Does it solve your problem? Edit: Another option: https://play.tailwindcss.com/HJ7GhicKHu